# Why select top ... order by indexed column still sort?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I created the following index to cover the select top statement.

```
-- Column A, B have type of int
create unique index ix_ on T (A, B) with (data_compression = page) 
-- tried to create non-unique index too and the execution plan is the same

select top 20 A, B from T order by A, B -- 19 seconds
select top 20 A, B from T -- return result instantly
```

However, it still take a while (19 seconds on my table which has 50 million rows) and execution plan shows there is still a "Sort"?

The execution plan shows

> Select (Cost: 0%) ← Top (Cost: 0%) ← Parallelism (Gather Streams) (Cost: 0%) ← Sort (Top N Sort) Cost: 93% ← Index Scan (NonClustered) [T.ix_] Cost: 7%

---

**Execution Plan**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.4100.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="20" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="552.009" StatementText="select  top 20 A A, B B --, checksum(*) cs&#xA;from T with (index(ix_))&#xA;order by A, B" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x1531573504856080" QueryPlanHash="0x5D4FED760C34AF43" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="8" MemoryGrant="1024" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="2" CompileCPU="2" CompileMemory="256">
            <ThreadStat Branches="1" UsedThreads="8">
              <ThreadReservation NodeId="0" ReservedThreads="8" />
            </ThreadStat>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="16" SerialDesiredMemory="24" RequiredMemory="896" DesiredMemory="960" RequestedMemory="1024" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="1024" MaxUsedMemory="896" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="768000" EstimatedPagesCached="768000" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="8" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="2E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="552.009">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="20" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                <TopExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(20)">
                    <Const ConstValue="(20)" />
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </TopExpression>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="0.0286101" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" NodeId="1" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="552.009">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="20" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Parallelism>
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="212.739" EstimateIO="303.269" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20" LogicalOp="TopN Sort" NodeId="2" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="551.98">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="20" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="12" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="0" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <TopSort Distinct="false" Rows="20">
                        <OrderBy>
                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                          </OrderByColumn>
                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                          </OrderByColumn>
                        </OrderBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="5.81245" EstimateIO="30.16" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="42226500" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="3" Parallel="true" Partitioned="true" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="35.9724" TableCardinality="42226500">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="3993270" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="2713924" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="8866373" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="10625143" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="4254726" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="3195887" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="3626671" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="4950538" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <RunTimePartitionSummary>
                            <PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="41">
                              <PartitionRange Start="1" End="41" />
                            </PartitionsAccessed>
                          </RunTimePartitionSummary>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="true" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="B" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="A" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Index="[ix_]" Alias="[T]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                      </TopSort>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Parallelism>
                </RelOp>
              </Top>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: I am not sure but an unique index does not help in performance I think you need a plain index

Comment: I tried plain index first and it's the same.

Comment: what are the datatypes of A and B ?

Comment: The are all int

Comment: What other indexes are on the table?

Comment: Yes are there any other indexes on this table ? Maybe if you create 2 indexes, one for each column ?

Comment: There are other indexes which were not used for the query.

Comment: Are you sure the index is created in the same order as the keys in the `order by` and there are no other keys?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I did a search on "A, B" and it hit both the order by and create index statements.

Comment: Get an XML of **actual** execution plans for both fast and slow queries and include them in the question. If XML is too big, use pastebin.com or something similar.

Comment: I created a table with two columns and created same index. Ran `select` query, execution does not include any sort operation. I created another table without the Index then ran `Select` it is same as your execution plan. So the problem is index is not getting used. Did you update the statistics and checked the query?

Comment: @Prdp did you use `order by`? The index is used in my case. The partial execution plan shows the index is scanned.

Comment: Include the actual execution plan. Your description is missing something.

Comment: @MartinSmith The execution plan is included.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov The question has been updated.

Comment: Is the table partitioned on column B?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes. That's why the index ix_ was created to cover the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table is partitioned by B.

The index inherits this partitioning scheme unless you specify otherwise. For example with

```
create unique index ix_ on T (A, B)  with (data_compression = page) on [primary]
```

(In which case it becomes non aligned and prevents some operations such as metadata only switching)

The lowest "A" value might be in any partition.

This isn't optimised very well. You can keep the aligned index and use this rewrite [based on the code here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables)

```
SELECT TOP 20 A, B 
FROM sys.partitions AS P
  CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 20 A, B 
                FROM dbo.T
                WHERE $PARTITION.YourPartitionFunction(T.B) = P.partition_number 
                ORDER BY A,B
                ) AS A
WHERE P.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T')
AND P.index_id = INDEXPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('dbo.T'), 'ix_', 'IndexID' )
ORDER BY  A,B
```

It will get the top 20 rows from each of the 41 partitions (without a sort) then just sort the 820 rows that result from that to get the final top 20 (rather than the whole 42 million).

Comment: But the index ix_ is not partitioned and the query uses the index?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - the index is partitioned. See `PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="41"` in your plan. - [If partition_scheme_name or filegroup is not specified and the table is partitioned, the index is placed in the same partition scheme, using the same partitioning column, as the underlying table.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, besides metadata only switch., Is there any other drawback of creating extra non aligned index?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - having the ability to switch partitions in and out quickly is the only reason I've ever used partitioning. So that would be a show stopper for me. I've never worked with non aligned indexes so not sure if you will encounter other problems. I'd keep the index aligned and use the workaround.

Comment: I just want to note that this is brilliant.